# Play! Framework on Heroku: validation.keep() isn't working over HTTPS

Tags: https, heroku, playframework, session-cookies

I'm using Heroku to deploy my Play! framework app.  I have a form that uses the standard structure of

```
public static void showForm() {
    render();
}

public static void handleForm(@Required param, @Required otherParam, etc) {
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        validation.keep();
        showForm();
    } else {
        //process form parameters
    }
}
```

This works fine on:

- dev machine running HTTP at `localhost:9000`
- heroku running HTTP at `www.myapp.com`
- dev machine running HTTPS at `localhost:9443`

However, for forms that do this on Heroku over HTTPS at `secure.myapp.com` using hostname-based SSL, the validations don't show up.  I think the problem is that `validation.keep()` isn't working.

If `validation.keep()` makes a cookie, and the problem has something to do with the difference between `www.myapp.com` and `secure.myapp.com`, then I might have a deeper problem because:

- I already have `application.defaultCookieDomain=.myapp.com`, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979073/https-redirect-and-login-cookies-on-heroku-with-play-framework).
- I think that both the GET and the POST are happening over HTTPS, so I think they have the same domain anyway...

  - The form's GET is definitely over HTTPS
  - When the form's data is processed, its result is definitely shown over HTTPS
  - I guess it's possible that the POST is happening over HTTP (and thus `www.*` instead of `secure.*`, but I'm not sure how to check).

Anybody have any guesses as to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently an incompatibility in the ssl (x-forwarded-proto) support for play on heroku that causes all requests to be considered insecure.

https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1385-requests-are-never-secure-on-heroku-when-using-ssl

So maybe this is related to the cookies your browser is sending back?