# Grails application on Heroku with ssl

Tags: grails, heroku

I have deployed a grails application on Heroku  at jetty runner.

I have purchase a SSL certificate from dnsSimple and successfully configured it considering when I hit the "https://mydomainname.com" I can see the certificate information.

Now I want to force all communication on https.
I have tried the following things but nothing worked so far:
[grails -  simple App to test spring-security-core secure-channel on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105084/grails-simple-app-to-test-spring-security-core-secure-channel-on-heroku)
[grails - spring-security-core secure-channel causing redirect loop (on Heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090709/grails-spring-security-core-secure-channel-causing-redirect-loop-on-heroku)
and a lot of other post recommending to use a filter for https  but no luck.
Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would be applied in Grails but here is the way to do it with Play: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512887/xforwardedsupport-for-https-play-support-on-heroku-failing

Comment: SO needs a downvote option for comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section "Using the Spring Security Core plugin" in the Heroku plugin docs where it discusses the `useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity` property: http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-heroku/docs/manual/guide/2%20Usage.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Burt. I have done every thing what are define in plugin docs and my application is running on heroku successfully. when I enter the domain.com with https prefix in address bar it serve the on https but when i enter domain.com it is not redirecting to https . Can you please tell me how I can force the app to redirect it on https..

Comment: @Amit did you ever get this to work? I was playing around with this on Amazon Elastic beanstalk ( Tried it on Heroku as well  )  and could not get passed the redirect problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems due to wrong case of “'x-forwarded-proto” header used in spring security core and “X-FORWARDED-PROTO” header used by heroku  Load balancer for https based url. Following link worked for me. 
[Heroku Forum](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/grails-spring-security-core-securechannel-definition-causes-redirect-loop/219/2)